# Asimov's Foundation Epic the 'granddaddy of sci fi'?

Tags: isaac-asimov, foundation

What are the big influences that Asimov's Foundation Saga has had on other science fiction franchises?

Comment: Back in my neck of the woods, RPG.SE, we allow some questions that don't always stick to the rules, like system-recommendation questions because we are heavy on the quality control with the answers. If we could do that here we'd have 'good subjective' answers that would be truly beneficial to the site.

Comment: The question does not have to be closed, but it should definitely be refined and expanded upon. In its current form it is all but useless.

Comment: As I said in chat, this is akin to asking what influences Tolkien had on Fantasy. Well, if an answer to either question is detailed enough to be *complete*, then it will also be the size of an encyclopedia. VTC'd as NARQ in its current form.

Comment: Any suggestions or improvements welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if Asimov was the first writer to postulate a Galactic Empire, but surely he popularized the concept a lot.

Comment: well, maybe not the granddaddy of sci-fi.  He is definitely in line for being the father of the "serious" multi-novel universe (not counting for space opera like Lensman etc.)

Answer (score 4):

Coruscant == Trantor.  OK, not exactly identical, but it was a MAJOR influence, and is acknowledged.

Comment: Also, mentalics = the force